# How to store drag&drop to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, local-storage

hope you can help!

I am working on a school assignment with local storage and drag & drop, so I am very new to this. I'm making a kind of task manager, similar to Trello, with tasks, members and different lists.

The problem I am having is that the things I drag are "reset" if I refresh the page. How can I fix it so it stays where I drop it?

Here the tasks are created:

```
function renderTasks() {
    var outputTask = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("outputTask")) || [];
    var outputTaskEl = document.getElementById("outputTasks");
    outputTaskEl.innerHTML = "";
    for (var product of outputTask) {
        var productTwo = document.createElement("div");
        productTwo.setAttribute('class', 'task');

        productTwo.setAttribute('draggable', true); 

        var {task,member,deadline} = product;

        productTwo.innerHTML = 
        "<div id='task'>" + 
            "<p>" + product.task + "</p>" + 
            "<ul>" +
                "<li><img id='pencil-img' src='images/pencil.png' alt='task-options. Pencil'>"+ 
                    "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>" +
                    "<li><a href='#' onclick='deleteTask(" + product.id + ")'>Delete task</a></li>" +
                    "<li><a href='#' onclick='editTask(" + product.id + ")'>Edit task</a></li>" +
                    "</ul>"
                "</li>" + 
            "</ul>";
        outputTaskEl.appendChild(productTwo);
    }

        for ( i = 0; i < outputTask.length; i++){
            var taskId = document.getElementsByClassName("task");
            taskId[i].id = "task" + (i + 1);
        }
}
```

And this is the drag and drop code:

```
function dragDropItems() {
    const taskItems = document.querySelectorAll('.task'); 
    const taskFields = document.querySelectorAll('.taskField');

    for (let i = 0; i < taskItems.length; i++) {
        const item = taskItems[i];

        item.addEventListener('dragstart', function () {
            draggedItem = item; 
            setTimeout(function () {
            }, 0)
        }); 

        item.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {}, 0);
        })

        for (let j = 0; j < taskFields.length; j ++) {
            const list = taskFields[j]; 
            draggedItem = item;
            list.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }); 
            list.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }); 
            list.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                this.append(draggedItem); 
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save element's position on drop and then use it again, this might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Save object
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(obj))

// Get object
let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'))
```